# Insert alphanumeric value into varchar type column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Hi i am trying to insert a alphanumeric value `46e0d48d-bca1-11e7-991f-2c27d70ced1d` into an varchar type column in a table. I am inserting through a variable but getting 1604 error that is syntax is not right. Here is the code

```
    SET @sql = CONCAT('insert into ', @user_table_name, ' 
                    (user, user2, message, mesg_type, date_time, mesg_read_status)
                    values (',@user_id,',',@user2_id,',',@message,',',@mesg_type,',',@date_time,',',@read_status,')'
                   );
select @sql;    
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

For `user` column i am passing the alphanumeric value `46e0d48d-bca1-11e7-991f-2c27d70ced1d`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learn to use parameters:

```
SET @sql = CONCAT('
insert into ', @user_table_name, ' (user, user2, message, mesg_type, date_time, mesg_read_status)
    values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
                  ');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt USING @user_id, @user2_id, @message, @mesg_type, @date_time, @read_status;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Don't munge query strings with parameter values.  That makes the code harder to debug, prone to errors, more difficult to read, and opens another line of attack for SQL injection.

Comment: tried that ,it gave error that the user field cannot have null value

Comment: @pramodaravind . . . Then you better be sure that `@user_id` does not have a `NULL` value.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SET @sql = CONCAT('insert into ', @user_table_name, ' 
                (user, user2, message, mesg_type, date_time, mesg_read_status)
                values (\'',@user_id,'\',',@user2_id,',',@message,',',@mesg_type,',',@date_time,',',@read_status,')'
               );
select @sql;    
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

This statement should work. Give it a try

Comment: Also make sure that the length of the column is big enough to accomodate the value you are inserting. Elese the value will be auto truncated.